# Чи є слово "потомство" калькою з російської?

Tags: росіянізм

Був дуже здивований, дізнавшись, що слово *потомство* є повною калькою з російської. Деякі словники дають ще варіант перекладу у множині - *нащадки*, але якось це незвично звучить.

Так яке слово слід використовувати українською - *нащадки* чи *потомство*?

Comment: Поправив форматування. Текст, що заключений у `backticks`, призначений для програмного коду. Програми-читачі екрану (screen readers) читають його по окремій літері, як абревіатуру, і тому на мовних сайтах його не варто використовувати. У нас є [стаття на Meta](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/43/8), вона містить багато корисної інформації, хоча, можливо, потребує допрацювання.

Answer (score 9):

***Потомство*** не є калькою з російської, а має спільне для української та російської коріння.

Слова *потомство*, *потомок* [походять](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_2003/EtSlUkrM_2003.pdf) від старослов'янського ***потомънь*** "наступний". Останнє пов'язане з праслов'янським *[potomъkъ]*, що походить від словосполучення ***po tomь*** - "потім, пізніше".

Окрім російського *потомок*, схожі слова є у білоруській (*патомак*), польській та чеській (*potomek*), словацькій (*potomok*), болгарській (*потомък*), македонськый (*потомок*), сербохорватській (*потомак*), словенській (*potomec*) та інших мовах.

***Нащадок*** [також](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/978-966-00-0197-8/978-966-00-0197-8.pdf) сягає корінням праслов'янської і утворене від слова ***čędo*** - "дитина":

[image]

Тому, думаю, можна послуговуватись обома словами - як *[нащадки](http://sum.in.ua/s/nashhadok)*, так і *[потомство](http://sum.in.ua/s/potomstvo)* (звертаючи увагу на відтінки їх значень).

Answer (score 7):

Етимологічний словник української мови. Том 5. 2003 рік.

> Потомок - похідне від потім, пізніше.

Етимологічний словник української мови. Том 6. 2012 рік.

> Нащадок - щадок. Щадок - утворене від чадо (дитина).

Тобто якщо хочете зробити акцент на тому, що потім, після вас - то потомок. А якщо потрібно зробити акцент на тому, що це ваша дитина - тоді нащадок.

Comment: Побачила вашу відповідь вже після того, як додала свою) (довго не оновлювала вкладку)